# Making background fit the screen (desktop/mobile)

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm a noob and currently working on my first site (for a friend). It's super rough right now. I have been hung up on trying to make this site mobile. The problem is there are these white gaps at the edges of the screen (on both desktop and mobile). I'm trying to make it full screen on desktop/mobile and have tried using 'container-fluid', but it didn't seem to work. Any help/tips/advice would be much appreciated. Here is what I have so far in codepen:
html:

```css
h1,
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}
.navbar {
  padding: 10px 0px 0px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  background-color: #7F462C;
}
.navbar a {
  color: #3FFF00;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 15px 10px 10px 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.navbar-default {
  border: none;
}
.navbar a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FDD017;
}
.christiana-flag {
  width: 45px;
  height: 30px;
}
.navbar li {
  display: inline;
}
.home {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Latto';
  color: #7F462C;
  background: url('http://blackgoldcompost.net/images/LeafBackground_227325_1800x1205_50.jpg') no-repeat center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
.intro > h1 {
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.intro {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!--Navigation-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role='navigation'>
    <ul class='pull-left'>
      <li>
        <a href='#'>
          <img class='christiana-flag' src='#'>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='pull-right'>
      <li><a href='#home'>Home</a>
        <li><a href='#about'>About</a>
          <li><a href='#how'>How it works</a>
            <li><a href='#service'>Service Area</a>
              <li><a href='#sign-up'>Sign-up</a>
                </u>
  </nav>
  <!--Home screen-->
  <div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-md-12'>
        <div class='home'>
          <div class='intro'>
            <h1>South Austin Compost</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--About-->
  <div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row'>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It is recommended that you create a jsfiddle to help us help you.

Comment: please make a minimal example that demonstrate the problem. Does the font Roboto affect this in any way or do you see the problem both with and without that part? Omit it! This way you are much more likely to get a quick answer.

Comment: The roboto font didn't affect it in any way when I substituted another font for it.....Also setting the margin to 0 didn't affect it.

Answer (score 1):

Tried setting body's `margin: 0;`?

That would be my guess looking at the css supplied without a jsFiddle. Hope it helps.

Comment: If this serves you well, I'd love it if you would accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set the margin of the body to 0, and it'll fix it for you.